# How do I shutdown a node project started by Forever? ungit

Tags: node.js, shutdown, forever

I'm using the open source project called Ungit.  It is based on node.js and I really enjoy it but I don't know how to shut it off other than rebooting the whole box.

Ungit is using "forever-monitor" to have a process run forever.  So when I do `nohup ungit > /dev/null &` I can't shut it down by killing it's process as it will restart it.

I have looked up forever-monitor project and I was able to install it globally and try to shut it by running `forever stop [number]` but `forever list` shows nothing and I don't know how to shut it down.

Thanks for any advices,

Answer (score 4):

with `forever list` you can see list of forever process 
with `forever stop 0` you can stop first process  .
with forever stop myscript.js  you can stop a process with name of script

Answer (score 0):

find the process that forever-monitor is running under and kill it first then kill the ungit process.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/